# How do I use a Minitel terminal as a linux dumb terminal

Tags: linux, serial

I recently purchased a US version of the Alcatel Minitel terminal. I think it's a 1B version. Pictures of it here:

http://www.catpa.ws/pics/minitel2.jpg

http://www.catpa.ws/pics/minitel3.jpg

I tried connecting a null modem to the 25 pin port on the back and plugging it into a linux box running agetty but I couldn't get it to show any signs of being connected. I used Google Translate to translate this document into English: http://mirabellug.org/wikini/upload/Documentations_minitel.pdf

As far as I can tell, you take it out of videotex mode by typing Fcnt-T A, then turn off local echo with Fcnt-T E, then set it to 4800 baud with Fcnt-P 4. I presume Fcnt refers to the "CTRL" key on my terminal. But I think I'm doing something wrong, because it doesn't look like it's recognising the keystrokes, because "Fcnt-T A" just prints the letter A to the screen, which is not what you'd expect a function key combo to do.

Has anyone used these minitel terminals as a linux terminal, and if so, please can you share how to configure the minitel to run as a terminal ? Is the 25 pin plug even the correct port to use ? I read something online that indicated you're supposed to use the 5 pin DIN plug instead, is that right ? If so, what's the 25 pin plug for ? If I am supposed to use the DIN plug, does anyone know the pinouts so I can make a cable ?

Comment: That's one crazy but awesome project =D

Comment: Friend and I are struggling with this same project. The problem with the Alcatel terminal is that the serial port is actually 6-pin which is a rather uncommon layout (different from all the French Minitel terminals we've seen). I built a serial cable on the assumption that the pinouts would be the same as on the C64 but this didn't work:
See: http://pinouts.ru/SerialPorts/SerialIOC64_pinout.shtml

I just bought a serial tester board to try and determine the correct pinout but am kind of stumbling blindly through this. Looking forward to suggestions from folks with more RS232 experience.

Comment: txtmsg, I have a unit like yours; see answer below.

Comment: Your images have gone missing.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across a Minitel 1B made for the US market and got it running. There are a couple of differences from the French version: it runs off 120VAC, it has a 6 pin DIN connector instead of 5 pin, and it uses RS232 line levels instead of 5V TTL. The pinout is below; pin locations assume you're behind the unit facing towards the connector.

- pin 1 (upper right) - RX
- pin 3 (bottom) - ground
- pin 5 (upper left) - TX

Like the unit described above it defaults to 1200 7E1. It also appears to use slightly different "Fnct" commands than the French model; here's what I've sussed out so far:

- Fnct-B 1 : set baud rate to 1200.
- Fnct-B 4 : set baud rate to 4800.
- Fnct-M E : toggle echo.
- Fnct-M A : 80-column ANSI mode. The text will be noticeably dimmer in this mode (although you can set bold text with ESC [ 1 m, which will be closer to the brightness you see at boot).
- Fnct-M V : 40-column Videotex mode

I'm talking to it with an FTDI cable passed through a max232. They're fun little terminals!

Comment: It has been ages since I played with one of these, but, if memory serves, you are correct. There ought to be an undocumented 9600 baud setting too, but for the life of me I can 't recall the key-combo.

Answer (score 2):

The correct plug to use is the 5 pin DIN, named "Peri-informatique".

Useful pins are (DIN pin numbering can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector)):

1. RX input
2. 0V ground
3. TX output

Electric levels are 5V TTL. Default protocol is 1200 baud, one parity bit, even parity.

Here are some resources, unfortunatelly in french:

- [Minitel 1 bistandard, notice](http://yip.free.fr/bidouilles/minitel/notice_alcatel/)
- [How to build a Minitel/RS232 cable](http://www.epi.asso.fr/fic_pdf/b47p207.pdf)
- [Connecting and configuring a minitel to a Linux PC](http://yip.free.fr/bidouilles/minitel/terminal.html)

Comment: What about the function key commands ? Are they necessary to tell the Minitel to use the serial port or "take it out of videotex mode" ? It still seems like they aren't doing anything so I'm wondering if I have the command keys wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've configured your serial port along those lines:
http://www.vanemery.net/Linux/Serial/serial-console.html

I propose you try out different baudrate settings on each side or contact the guy who wrote the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, You have to use the `FCTN` button, not `CTRL`. tested on a Phillips minitel2.
press together `FTC`N and `T` then release it. then press `A`.
do the same for `FCTN+T`, `E` , `FCTN+p`, `4`